# How to get a count of disjointed clusters in a subgraph

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-algorithm, neo4j-apoc, subgraph

Is there **Cypher** query or **apoc/algo** method to return a **count** of the isolated clusters in a subgraph?

[image: 2 Clusters returned by MATCH p=()-[r:RELATION]->() RETURN p]

The query/method would return **2**

**UPDATE:**
The **setCount** value returned by **algo.unionFind** seems to do the trick.

**UPDATE:**
There's also **communityCount** they're both the same value...anybody know the **difference?**

Answer (score 1):

Looking in the [source code](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-graph-algorithms/blob/d24554fb06ce106a5913f0c4694f6708b6968779/algo/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphalgo/impl/UnionFindProcExec.java#L155), the `setCount` and `communityCount` values in a `UnionFindResult` are set to the same value (and never changed). So, there is no difference.